# How to prevent Visual Studio (2012) from capturing CAPSLOCK key

Tags: visual-studio-2012, capslock

I am a Humanized Enso Launcher user. What Enso does is it replaces the functionally useless CAPSLOCK key, with a nice keyboard driven program launcher, so if you want to start, for instance, putty you depress CAPSLOCK, and type open putty on the keyboard, and enso will launch putty for you. Clever right?

Well unless you happen to work with Visual studio, in which case you just wrote OPEN PUTTY in all caps in your source code, because for some reason Visual Studio thinks you want to shout at your source code (when it's really the editor you want to shout at).

Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode then you will probably need to run Enso in that mode as well so that it can interact with VS